# How to change menus in java (using swing)

Tags: java, swing

I am making a game of pong. I already made an applet version, but now I want to migrate it into JFrame version. But here comes my problem of main menu. I've made a class called Menu, which extends JComponent. It has 4 buttons to choose from. I'd like to have buttons: "play local multiplayer", "play online multiplayer", "settings" and "exit". Exit works just fine. BUT there comes the problem. I want that when I click "settings", the main menu unloads and the settings menu renders on screen. But only thing that my code does is that it freezes the frame...

Menu class:

```
class Menu extends JComponent implements ActionListener{
public int selectionNo;
String TT;
JButton Choice1, Choice2, Choice3, Choice4;
int i;
Font TitleFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50), Text = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 35);
Image background = getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/res/background.jpg"));

public Menu(String title, String choice1, String choice2, String choice3, String choice4){
    i = 0;
    TT = title;
    Choice1 = new JButton(choice1);
    Choice2 = new JButton(choice2);
    Choice3 = new JButton(choice3);
    Choice4 = new JButton(choice4);
    Choice1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    Choice1.setFont(Text);
    Choice1.addActionListener(this);
    Choice2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    Choice2.setFont(Text);
    Choice2.addActionListener(this);
    Choice3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    Choice3.setFont(Text);
    Choice3.addActionListener(this);
    Choice4.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    Choice4.setFont(Text);
    Choice4.addActionListener(this);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    while (i<6){
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 30)));
        i++;
    }
    add(Choice1);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));
    add(Choice2);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));
    add(Choice3);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));
    add(Choice4);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    //super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
    g.setFont(TitleFont);
    g.setColor(Color.decode("#FF9933"));
    g.drawString(TT, 320, 110);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == Choice1){
        selectionNo = 1;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == Choice2){
        selectionNo = 2;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == Choice3){
        selectionNo = 3;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == Choice4){
        selectionNo = 4;
    }
}
}
```

When selectionNo is 3 (settings button) I call this code:

```
System.out.println("Settings yet to be implemented");
frame.remove(menu);
menu = new Menu("Settings", "test", "test", "test", "test");
frame.add(menu);
menu.repaint();
```

Name of my JFrame object is frame and the name of (previously) main menu object is menu.

EDIT: I think that the problem is somewhere in paint methods.

Can anyone please help me??

Comment: Use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: No, I want to remove old menu and add a new one.

Comment: But then you'd want your old menu back sometime later...right (by the use of some back button probably)? Save yourself the micromanagement of coding, and use cardlayout. Have two panels which represent the different screens, and then switch between them appropriately. Much easier to implement and the code looks much cleaner that way.

Comment: Okay, i can try. Where to put the cardlayout? Directly into menu class or into frame?

Comment: The frame has card layout, and based on button clicks, the frame changes its screen. The main menu would be one of the panel in the card layout. The settings screen would be other. The game play screen would be another panel in the card layout. You get the idea.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. :)